# Implement app instance ID for Ionic/Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, device, uuid, instanceid

I have been using the Cordova device plugin to access the UUID. For iOS this is unique per instance rather than per device. Alas this is not the case with Android. I wanted to use it as a means to recover a lost connection but don't want it to persist between installs.

How can I uniquely identify an instance of an Ionic app such that it remains the same through updates but is reset on uninstall? The problem arose because iOS was occasionally wiping $localStorage. In case of file/storage corruption or some other local catastrophe I would like to be able to identify the incoming request and at least acknowledge the user data still exists.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: I switched to using an auth system and identifying instances by user/password.